# How to POST JSON data over HTTP in Java?

Tags: java, json, http, post

I'm new in JSON and am working on a Coinbase API. [See here](https://www.coinbase.com/api/doc/1.0/transactions/send_money.html).

So I'm trying to POST this data over HTTP:

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "to": "user1@example.com",
    "amount": "1.234",
    "notes": "Sample transaction for you"
  }
}
```

How would I do this in Java?

I know how to create a program to `GET` a **response** but not how to `POST` a **request**.

Here is my Program for **Response**:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import com.coinbase.api.Coinbase;
import com.coinbase.api.CoinbaseBuilder;

public class CoinbaseExample {

    static String API_KEY = "My API KEY";

    static String API_SECRET = "MY API SECRET";

    public static String getHttp(String url, String body)
            throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        String nonce = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String message = nonce + url + (body != null ? body : "");

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(API_SECRET.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256"));
        String signature = new String(Hex.encodeHex(mac.doFinal(message.getBytes())));

        HttpRequestBase request;
        if (body == null || body.length() == 0)
            request = new HttpGet(url);
        else {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(body));
            request = post;
        }
        request.setHeader("ACCESS_KEY", API_KEY);
        request.setHeader("ACCESS_SIGNATURE", signature);
        request.setHeader("ACCESS_NONCE", nonce);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null)
            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        return null;
    }

}
```

How to create this similar program to **Post** request?

Comment: have you tried yourself??

Comment: Ya.. i tried myself.. But always get stuck!! :( that's why i came here to ask.. :( pls help!

Comment: explain the problem , what do you get? an error? request not sent, is it empty? ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String url = "http://yoururl.com";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

//add reuqest header
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

//print result
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Comment: parameter is a name value pair where in <value> you will send your json.

Comment: What is `USER_AGENT` in your program??. it's giving me an error.. this is not defined ..

Comment: replace the whole line with con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.1");

Comment: Check your server side code. and check if you are posting to valid url.